# angular 2 ng-bootstrap datepicker popup

Tags: angular, datepicker, ng-bootstrap

Hi I am investigating on ng-bootstrap datepicker. I looked at the demo code and was able to get it to work in my application.

However, if I added more than 1 datepicker input tags, only one is working. Below are the code I created. I tried to change the #d to #d1 and #d2 (also change the toggle() part) and the page spits out errors.

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp" [(ngModel)]="newItem.EndTime"  ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" required>
    <div class="input-group-addon" (click)="d.toggle()" >
        <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp" [(ngModel)]="newItem.StartTime"  ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" required>
    <div class="input-group-addon" (click)="d.toggle()" >
        <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also tried to wrap it with a component and it allowed me to have multiple datepicker instance for different properties. However, it didn't seem to pass the value back to the parent component.

new.campaign.html

```
<div class="row col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <label for="campaignStartTime">Start Time</label>
        <datepicker-popup [(model)]="newItem.StartTime" (modelChange)="updateDate($event)" [required]="true" id="campaignStartTime"></datepicker-popup>
    </div>
</div>
```

datepicker-popup.component.ts

```
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
selector: 'datepicker-popup',
templateUrl: 'app/campaign/datepicker-popup.html'
    })
    export class DatepickerPopupComponent {
    @Input()
    model:any;
    @Input()
    id:string;
    @Input()
    required:boolean=false;
    @Output()
    modelChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(){    }
    updateModel(){
    let date = this.model;
    date = '12/22/2016'
    this.modelChange.emit(date);
    }
    }
```

datepicker-popup.html

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp [(ngModel)]="model"  (change)="updateModel()" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" required>
    <div class="input-group-addon" (click)="d.toggle()" >
        <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone point me to the right direction to solve the issue?

Comment: Could you use https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap for angular2?

Comment: @HarryNinh AFAIK ng2-bootstrap does _not_ have support for datepickers in popups and a user is asking specifically for https://ng-bootstrap.github.io so your comment is not helpful.

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource I'm using ng2-bootstrap in my current project for all date fields so I know it does support popup datepicker. And because he's looking for ng-bootstrap solution, I didn't post it as an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I tried to change the #d to #d1 and #d2 (also chancge the toggle() part) and the page spits out errors.

There must be something specific to your application going on since this is the right approach. A working code snippet:

```
 <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp1" [(ngModel)]="newItem.EndTime"  ngbDatepicker #d1="ngbDatepicker" required>
        <div class="input-group-addon" (click)="d1.toggle()" >
            <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp2" [(ngModel)]="newItem.StartTime"  ngbDatepicker #d2="ngbDatepicker" required>
        <div class="input-group-addon" (click)="d2.toggle()" >
            <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the live example in plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZC3dOX9anbbNUMPEEd5W?p=preview

Verify that you've got unique input names and that you use unique variable names pointing to a directive instance (`#d1`, `#d2` etc.). If you still face problems reproduce it in the plunker I've linked and open an issue in https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried it again and this time it works! It must be the late night and some odd thing going on at the time. Thank you!!!!

Comment: How for this will be feasible for reactive forms?