# ng-bootstrap for Angular 2 datepicker does not popup the calendar

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I cannot get the @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap datepicker to actually show a calendar.  I first tried within my own project, using the plunkr example from the documentation for multiple calendars.  All I got was a small rectangle, about 4 pixels tall and 30 pixels wide, with nothing inside.

[image]

I then searched SO and found [this example and plunkr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39653143/angular-2-ng-bootstrap-datepicker-popup/) and tried it, with the same result.

I generated a totally new Angular app with the Angular 2 CLI, installed the @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap, and added the code from the last plunkr.  This gives even worse results, not even showing the selector button.

[image]

Does anyone have insight into this?

update: I realized I didn't have font-awesome referenced, so after that my controls look like this and the calender does pop down, but this is not a good look!

[image]

Update 2:  Still trying to solve this.  I tried a different library with similar results-- the dropdown does not work.  I believe this is a problem with the dropdowns just not working in nested components.  I've compared all the libraries for the working version with the non-working and they are all the same.  The only difference is that the working one is in a top-level component and the non-working one is in a nested component.

Update 3: Solved.

2 things were involved.
1 - I had to combine the form-group and input-group classes into one div

2 - there was a TypeScript error in the console for an undefined variable.  I don't know why that would prevent the control from dropping down the calendar, since that variable had nothing to do with the form, but it did.  Once I fixed that, the calendar renders correctly.

Here's my sample code that works:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sub',
  templateUrl: './sub.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sub.component.css']
})
export class SubComponent implements OnInit {
  thisForm: FormGroup;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.thisForm = new FormGroup({
      dp1: new FormControl('')
    });
  }

  onSubmit(){}
}
```

```js
<form [formGroup]="thisForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

  <div class="form-group input-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" id="dp1" form-control-name="dp1" name="dp1"   ngbDatepicker #d1="ngbDatepicker" required>
    <div class="input-group-addon" (click)="d1.toggle()" >
      <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!thisForm.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] of what you have tried to your question.  How else are we supposed to know what your code is missing?

Comment: Great idea, but using Plunkr one has no idea what the underlying infrastructure is, what libraries are in place, etc.  I felt it would not help, since I used an existing complete and verifiable example to begin with, and it did not work.

Comment: Feel free to add the solution as an answer (instead of part of the question) and mark it as such.

Comment: I complete agree that having a plunkr is the way to go for `ng` questions.  However, your initial question only pointed to the example you found (and not what you did) so it is nearly impossible to know what's wrong with your code if we cannot see it.  That's why it's suggested you added a [mcve] to the question - Otherwise, we are all guessing

Comment: In my case, I have to include `bootstrap: 4.0.0-beta` to get the calendar selector popup work.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a similar kind of problem where my ng-bootstrap calendar pop-up was not working. 
what solved my problem was also mentioned in comments by John_J.

Actually, The ng-bootstrap repository contains a set of native Angular directives based on Bootstrap's markup and CSS. As a result no dependency on jQuery or Bootstrap's JavaScript is required. The only required dependencies are:

Angular (requires Angular version 4 or higher, tested with 4.0.3)
Bootstrap CSS (tested with 4.0.0-beta)

The solution is simple.

In your index.html:-

1. Add -`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">` into your `<head>`.
2. Then add- 
   `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

   `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

   `<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

   just above your ending  tag.
   And there you go...calendar starts working completely fine.Here's a [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) to the site you could get more details from.